# Nested reference not working in Swagger UI / OpenAPI 3

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

I have this OpenAPI 3.0 definition with a nested reference:

```yaml
Student:
    properties : &BaseStudent
    id:
      type: integer
      format: int64
      description: The ID of the new account.
    name:
      type: string
      description: The human-readable description of this account.
    address:
      $ref : 'address.yaml#/Address'

Address:
    properties : 
     <<* : BaseStudent
    city:
       type: string
      description: City.
    state:
      type: string
      description: State.
    
StudentMarks:
    <<: *BaseStudent
    makr1:
       type: string
      description: Mark1.
    mark2:
      type: string
      description: Mark2.
```

When I click the request tab in Swagger UI, it shows an error:

> Could not resolve reference because of: Could not resolve pointer: /components/schemas/components/schemas/Address does not exist in document

Actually the `Address` reference is supposed to be `/components/schemas/` only. I am not sure why it's referring `/components/schemas/components/schemas/Address`.

Is there any other way to specify the paths differently?

Comment: In which tool do you see this error - Swagger Editor, Codegen, or some other tool? What's in the `address.yaml` file?

Comment: I am seeing this error in Swagger UI page. My apis are working fine but when I click the request tab i am getting this error. Sorry, address.yaml made a typo. I updated it

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be caused by YAML anchors.

OpenAPI has a built-in way to reference definitions and do model composition - `$ref` and `allOf`. These keywords should generally be used instead of YAML anchors.

Try rewriting the schemas as follows and see if it resolves the issue:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:

    Student:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          description: The ID of the new account.
        name:
          type: string
          description: The human-readable description of this account.
        address:
          $ref : 'address.yaml#/Address'

    Address:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/BaseStudent'
        - properties:
            city:
              type: string
              description: City.
            state:
              type: string
              description: State.
    
    StudentMarks:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/BaseStudent'
        - properties:
            mark1:
              type: string
              description: Mark1.
            mark2:
              type: string
              description: Mark2.
```

Comment: Thanks Helen for the response. But when I try this I am getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\test\src\main\resources\schema\v0_1 (Access is denied) error. Is there any other configuration required for using allOf?

Comment: Where do you get this Java error? You said you were using Swagger UI but it's not a Java app.

Comment: Yes while building the project itself I am getting this error Helen.

Comment: What project? Building how?

Comment: We are generating class file every build. After using the allOf I am unable to build gettng the access denied error

Comment: Its Gradle based Java Project

Comment: Like, using Swagger Codegen or OpenAPI Generator to generate code from the API definition?

Comment: Swagger Codegen